# Return one row in sql lite query by id

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created an Android app with a pre-populated SQLite database(using SQLite Browser). Copying the file to the /data path on my phone worked perfectly, but I can't seem to get my head around something.

I need to get a row from a given ID, set this result in TextViews and when another ID is given update the TextViews with the new result. This ofcourse should be quite easy, so I've read everything from tutorials to information on the Android dev site and SO. For some reason I just don't seem to get this. Can someone help me get started with this or link me to some resource that explains this particulair situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code what you have did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cursor to get data from the database

```
  Database db = new Database(this);   

  Cursor yourdata = db.getDetails(this);
  if(yourdata!=null)
  {
  yourdata.moveToFirst();
   String value= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(databaseColumn);
   TextView youtextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
   youtextview .setText(value);
  }
```

Create getDetails() method in Database Class.

```
 public Cursor getDetails(Activity youactivity,
        int projectid) { 
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String from[] = { YourColumn}; 
    String where = ID+"="+projectid;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, Table, from, where, null, null, null, null, null); 
    return cursor;  
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Vinoth, I've created something that I cant seem to get posted but your answer certainly helps.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped you.. If you got answer just mark it as answer otherwise your question will be in non answered list..